# com.cra.figaro.algorithm.NotATargetException when using Figaro in Scala

Tags: scala, figaro-lang

Im just running into the following error when i try to run my code. I do not understand what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

```
com.cra.figaro.algorithm.NotATargetException
    at com.cra.figaro.algorithm.ProbQueryAlgorithm$class.check(ProbQueryAlgorithm.scala:68)
    at com.cra.figaro.algorithm.ProbQueryAlgorithm$class.probability(ProbQueryAlgorithm.scala:138)
    at com.cra.figaro.algorithm.sampling.WeightedSampler.probability(WeightedSampler.scala:25)
    at prob1.BetaBinomial$.runner1(BetaBinomial.scala:24)
```

Im executing in SBT with `runner1("HHHHTHHHHHHTHHTHHHTHH")`, i have other code in figaro that is working but this one just won't start.

```
package prob1

import com.cra.figaro.library.atomic.continuous.Beta
import com.cra.figaro.library.atomic.discrete.Binomial
import com.cra.figaro.language.Flip
import com.cra.figaro.algorithm.sampling.Importance

object BetaBinomial {
    def runner1(data: String){
      val outcomes = data
      val numTosses = outcomes.length
      val numObservedHeads = outcomes.count((c: Char) => c == 'H')
      val bias = Beta(2,5)
      val numberOfHeads = Binomial(numTosses, bias)
      val nextToss = Flip(bias)

      numberOfHeads.observe(numObservedHeads)
      val algorithm = Importance(bias) 
      algorithm.start()
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      algorithm.stop()
      //This is where i get the error
      val probHeads = algorithm.probability(nextToss, true)
      println("Probability of heads = " + probHeads)
      algorithm.kill()
      numberOfHeads.unobserve()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with figaro, but looking at the implementation of [`ProbQueryAlgorithm.check`](https://github.com/p2t2/figaro/blob/master/Figaro/src/main/scala/com/cra/figaro/algorithm/ProbQueryAlgorithm.scala#L68) indicates that the target you have specified is not part of the `queryTargets`. The `queryTargets` are initialized in the constructors of `Importance`/`WeightedSampler`:

```
abstract class WeightedSampler(override val universe: Universe, targets: Element[_]*) extends ProbQueryAlgorithm with Sampler {
  lazy val queryTargets = targets.toList
  ...
}

abstract class Importance(universe: Universe, targets: Element[_]*)
  extends WeightedSampler(universe, targets: _*) {
  ...
}
```

Did you try this?

```
val algorithm = Importance(bias, nextToss)
```